# How to set AND "&" multi conditions to remove rows with "!" data.table way R

Tags: r, data.table, subset, grepl

Generally remove expression of data.table works, `DT[!grepl("XXX",COLUMN),]`

**Target : Remove the rows with 3 conditions**

```
# Like : grepl("BB",RR) & grepl("XLKG",B) & grepl("GA",FF)
  RR    B FF
  1: AA  XLJ KA
  2: BB XLKG CA
  3: BB XLKG GA     <----- remove this rows
  4: BB XLKG FA
  5: BB XLCC GA   

# DATASET
DD <- data.table(RR=c("AA","BB","BB","BB","BB"),B=c("XLJ","XLKG","XLKG","XLKG","XLCC"),FF=c("KA","CA","GA","FA","GA"))
```

**Problem : The script below cannot apply multi remove expression**

```
DD[!grepl("BB",RR) & grepl("XLKG",B) & grepl("GA",FF),][]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: RR,B,FF
```

How can i achieve that ?
**Using grepl() is a must**

Comment: Parentheses: `DD[!(grepl("BB",RR) & grepl("XLKG",B) & grepl("GA",FF)),]` Fyi, there's an alias for `grepl` with two arguments: `DD[!(RR %like% "BB" & B %like% "XLKG" & FF %like% "GA"),]`

Comment: What Frank says, otherwise you want rows where RR is not BB, but B is XLKG and FF is GA

Comment: Related, I think: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1431

Comment: Thankyou Frank , one word tell solve my problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank and others have already pointed out: you need parentheses so your negation is negating the whole argument not just the first part.

Furthermore if you must use `grepl()` then `fixed = TRUE` will increase performance if you are not using any regex:

```
DD[!(grepl("BB", RR, fixed = TRUE) & grepl("XLKG", B, fixed = TRUE) & grepl("GA", FF, fixed = TRUE))]

   RR    B FF
1: AA  XLJ KA
2: BB XLKG CA
3: BB XLKG FA
4: BB XLCC GA
```

Comment: Thankyou snoram , especially the additional fixed = TRUE explanation !